# Error whilst trying to populate dimension table

Tags: sql, oracle, schema

Hi i'm attempting to populate a dimension table of a star schema however i run into a problem at the last line of code everything before this last bit of code works fine if anyone can help i'd appreciate it thanks.
This is all done on oracle apex and the code is below it's only the last line of code that comes up with error

ORA-01722: invalid number

ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SQL", line 1721

```
DROP table tmp_airport;
Create table tmp_airport as SELECT origin_airport FROM A2_STAGEAREA; 

DROP sequence loc_seq;

create sequence loc_SEQ
start with 1
increment by 1
maxvalue 10000
minvalue 1;

INSERT INTO SS_AIRPORT_DIM SELECT loc_seq.nextval, ORIGIN_AIRPORT FROM tmp_airport;
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code. please show the DDL for ALL the tables.

Comment: Hi I've removed the picture and added the code to the question sorry about that.

Comment: You still did not show the DLL for SS_AIRPORT_DIM  table.